# Bootstrap table actions not working on next page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

Currently I am working on a page with Bootstrap tables. These tables are autofilled. On the first page there are no problems to eliminate an element, because there is a confirmation message to eliminate.

When I go to the next page, and I want to eliminate the click on the "x" to eliminate it makes the action of deleting, but no confirmation message appears.

Here is the code

```
can('delete', $unit)
                                                    <form id="{{ $unit->id }}" style="display: inline-block;" method="post" action="{{ url("estates/$estate->uid/units/$unit->uid") }}">
                                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                                                        <button id="deleteUnit-{{ $unit->id }}" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger eliminar" rel="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Eliminar" name="eliminar" data-id="{{ $unit->id }}">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </form>
                                                @endcan
```

and

```
$().ready(function(){
        window.operateEvents = {
            'click .edit': function (e, value, row, index) {
                info = JSON.stringify(row);

                // swal('You click edit icon, row: ', info);
                console.log(row.actions);
            },
            'click .remove': function (e, value, row, index) {
                console.log(row);
                $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
                    field: 'id',
                    values: [row.id]
                });
            }
        };

        $table.bootstrapTable({
            toolbar: ".toolbar",
            showRefresh: false,
            search: true,
            showToggle: false,
            showColumns: true,
            pagination: true,
            searchAlign: 'left',
            pageSize: 10,
            clickToSelect: false,
            pageList: [10, 15, 20],

            formatShowingRows: function(pageFrom, pageTo, totalRows){
                $(window).resize(function () {
                    $table.bootstrapTable('resetView');
        });
                //do nothing here, we don't want to show the text "showing x of y from..."
            },
            formatRecordsPerPage: function(pageNumber){
                return pageNumber + " rows visible";
            },
            icons: {
                refresh: 'fa fa-refresh',
                toggle: 'fa fa-th-list',
                columns: 'fa fa-columns',
                detailOpen: 'fa fa-plus-circle',
                detailClose: 'fa fa-minus-circle'
            }
        });

        //activate the tooltips after the data table is initialized
        $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();

        $(window).resize(function () {
            $table.bootstrapTable('resetView');
        });



        $('[id^="deleteUnit-"]').on('click', function (e) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this)[0].getAttribute('data-id');

            swal({
                title: '¿Estás seguro?',
                text: "No es posible deshacer esta acción!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
                confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-info btn-fill",
                confirmButtonText: "Si, eliminar",
                cancelButtonClass: "btn btn-danger btn-fill",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: true
            }, function(isConfirm){
                if (isConfirm){
                    document.getElementById(id).submit();   
                }
            });

        });


    });
```

Here is an image[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Bij.png)

Comment: Your console should definitely tell you something

Comment: no, it doesn't...